# Mysql many to many relationship query. How to get all tags of filtered posts?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have gone through tons of questions about this issue here in Stackoverflow but I think this is different.

What I'm trying to do is give user ability to filter posts by tags so that one sees only the tags that are left for filtering. In other words if user selects tag "tag1", it show posts with that tag and also show other tags that post shares but hide tags that no visible post have after filtering.

I have tables **posts**, **posts_tags** and **tags**. Posts_tags have post_id and tag_id. I have managed to get post_ids available with specific tagset:

```
SELECT pt.post_id
FROM posts_tags pt
    INNER JOIN tags t
        ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
GROUP BY pt.post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 3;
```

Let's say this query gives post_ids 1, 2, 3:

```
post 1 has tag1, tag2, tag3 and tag4
post 2 has tag1, tag2, tag3 and tag5
post 3 has tag1, tag2, tag3 and tag6
```

Now my problem is **how to expand the query to return only tag4, tag5 and tag6** to user, because these tags are still available to filter posts further. How to achieve this?

Paying attention to performance would be also nice. I have 130000 posts, 6500 tags and bridge-table has 240000 rows.

edit: use scenario:

1. User seaches tags with autocomplete and selects multiple tags.
2. User retrieves posts based on submitted tags.
3. User searches more tags and at that point:

   I don't want to give full list but only the ones

   a. That haven't been selected yet.

   b. Are used in posts that were retrieved at step 2.

[image: Sample data]

---

**EDIT: FINAL QUERY BASED ON Mosty Mostacho's ANSWER:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT pt2.tag_id, t2.name FROM    
(SELECT pt1.post_id
    FROM posts_tags pt1
    INNER JOIN tags t1
        ON pt1.tag_id = t1.id
    WHERE t1.name in ('tag1','tag2','tag3')
    GROUP BY pt1.post_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) = 3) MatchingPosts
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt2 ON (MatchingPosts.post_id = pt2.post_id)
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON (pt2.tag_id = t2.id)
WHERE t2.name NOT IN ('tag1','tag2','tag3');
```

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions in SO, here is one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070927/mysql-many-to-many-select

or a quick search on SO
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D%20many%20to%20many

Comment: @beerwin Thanks! Did you notice that my query is exact copy from that question you linked? Thats because I got it from that question. But it won't solve my problem. Have you read what I stated at my first sentence?

Comment: Hmm, smells like `relational division`. http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is the best I can think of at 4:30 AM:

```
SELECT distinct tag_id FROM
    (SELECT pt1.post_id FROM pt1
    INNER JOIN tags t1 ON (pt1.tag_id = t1.id)
    WHERE t1.id IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY pt1.post_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) = 2) MatchingPosts
INNER JOIN pt2 ON (MatchingPosts.post_id = pt2.post_id)
WHERE (pt2.tag_id NOT IN (1, 2))
```

The (1, 2) are the tags you're looking for and the count, of course, will have to match the amount of tags you're using to filter.

Here is an [example](http://sqlize.com/K80KHIBmx5) (Notice I slightly changed the data)

Comment: Thank you very much! That pointed me to the right direction. I had to modify it a little to be able to use tag names and also return tag names. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean expand to only include tag4, tag5, tag6... why not just change your WHERE t.name in ( ) to reflect those tags...

OR... Do you mean it MUST include tags 1, 2, 3 but also any ONE of ( tag4 or tag5 or tag6 )...

If THAT is the case, I would change the where/having to the following...

```
WHERE t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6' )
GROUP BY pt.post_id
HAVING sum( if( t.name in ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ), 1, 0 )) = 3
  AND sum( if( t.name in  ('tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6' ), 1, 0 )) > 0
```

Comment: No. I'm sorry that I can't explain this well enough. In this case tag4-6 comes based on posts that have selected tags. We don't know them at advance. User selects tags-> them filter posts -> posts has tags that are not selected. I'm looking for the latter.

Comment: @Henri,  I would then take the effort to update your question, show about 20 entries with the different combinations with respective tags, and to the right of the sample data, indicate "I want these because..." event if its a foot-note reason such as "Include via (A)", or "Exclude via (B)"... that might help give a better mental indicator to those looking at the question

Comment: I try to improve it but I can't simply copy-paste sample data because it have to be disguised.

Comment: @Henri, you've disguised the scenario so far... if you want a solution, we need better scenario of what you ARE trying to get.