# MySql self JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
mysql> describe skill_usage;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| skill_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| job_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and know that in my data, there is a single `job_id` (6) which was used for both `skill_id` 3 and 4:

```
mysql>  select * from skill_usage;
+----------+--------+
| skill_id | job_id |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |
|        2 |      2 |
|        3 |      3 |     <----  matches only one part of the AND clause
|        3 |      4 |     <----  matches only one part of the AND clause
|        2 |      5 |
|        3 |      6 |     <==== matches both parts of the AND clause
|        4 |      6 |     <====
|        2 |      7 |
+----------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.job_id FROM skill_usage AS s1 
  INNER JOIN skill_usage AS s2 ON s1.job_id = s2.job_id
    WHERE s1.skill_id IN (3,4)
    AND   s2.skill_id IN (3,4)
```

which I thought meant "find all `job_id` which matches both `skill_id` 3 and `skill_id` 4".

Apparently not:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT s1.job_id FROM skill_usage AS s1
    ->   INNER JOIN skill_usage AS s2 ON s1.job_id = s2.job_id
    ->     WHERE s1.skill_id IN (3,4)
    ->     AND   s2.skill_id IN (3,4);
+--------+
| job_id |
+--------+
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      6 |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrongly? How should my query read? I think that it's time for a good book or Udemy course, but none that I own cover self join.

My query is correctly finding `job_id` = 6, but wrongly (IMO), finding `job_id` 3 and 4. I would expect them to fail the `AND` clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution.
(Refer [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8682de3f48826b554b3e1291342f896b))

```sql
select s1.job_id
  from skill_usage s1
  where s1.skill_id = 3
    and s1.job_id in (
                       select s2.job_id
                         from skill_usage s2
                        where s2.skill_id = 4
                     )
```

Comment: I am awarding this one the answer, because it seems easier to combine it to build complex queries. E.g "find job_id which has either skill Id 3 AND 4 OR skill_id 1)" becomes `select distinct s1.job_id
  from skill_usage s1
  where s1.skill_id = 3
    and s1.job_id in (
                       select s2.job_id
                         from skill_usage s2
                        where s2.skill_id = 4
                     )
    or s1.skill_id=1`  See fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b9a921882953da88078d253adac086b

Answer (score 4):

You may use aggregation here:

```
SELECT job_id
FROM skill_usage
WHERE skill_id IN (3, 4)
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING MIN(skill_id) <> MAX(skill_id);
```

This query should benefit from the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON skill_usage (skill_id, job_id);
```

Both the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses, as written, are *sargable*, and should be able to take advantage of this index.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but can you explain to me `HAVING MIN(skill_id) <> MAX(skill_id)`? what is that doing? Would it work just as as well if I were searching for `skill_id` 2 and 9999?

Comment: Just think about it: If we restrict to just _two_ skills, _and_ a matching job group has a smallest and largest skill which are not the same, then it implies that this job has both 3 and 4.  Note: We could have used `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill_id) = 2`, but then MySQL might not be able to use the index I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer, and for the clarification. Before I ask another question, I will try to figure out for myself how match (`skill_id` = 3 AND 4) OR (`skill_id` = 5 AND 6)`.

Comment: Easy, peasy! Just an `OR skill_id in (x,y)` after the `WHERE`.

Comment: Which now leaves me puzzling over more complex expressions. E.g (skill_id = 3 AND skill_id = 4) OR (skill_id = 5 AND 6) OR (skill_id = 2) Probably 2 queries & join them somehow ...

Comment: No...just more logic in the having clause.

Comment: I just can't get it to work :-(  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c0c6f32586909d17fa01387226a0d98d