# how to fetch the records based on value is exist in the column or not in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this data is getting from some emp table table:--->"`php,codeigniter,seo,html,javascript,techsupport,html,hr,finance`"

here my problem based on the above data

the following table if any string matches skill from above data then show that id

table:

```
id      skill
---------------------
1      php
2      php,hr
3      javascript,html,seo
4      sap
5      oracleapps
```

the result should only display 1,2,3 rows only it is possible to get that data?

I am using this query but it is fetch exact match records only

```
select * from seekerdetails jsd
where find_in_set(  jsd.key_skills,( select lower( GROUP_CONCAT(key_skills))
  from 
empjobs))
```

Comment: this question has been asked many times. you need to change your table structure, creating [many-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070927/mysql-many-to-many-select)

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, but that is not always possible. For example if you have a legacy product and a limited budget.

Answer (score -1):

First, explode your `$table` list, and then add it one-by-one to the `FIND_IN_SET` call:

```
 $t = explode(",",$table);
 $q = "SELECT * FROM seekerdetails WHERE ".
       "FIND_IN_SET(".implode("', key_skills) OR FIND_IN_SET('", $t).", key_skills)";
```