# SQL that return specific ids in group of 5

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `articles` table with `id` and `created_by`
And `users` table with `id` and `name`

I need to write SQL that retrieve 5 or less articles for users 1,2,3,4,5,6,...
If I use `limit 5`, it will limit the result to 5 records, but I need to limit the result to 5 for each specific user.

I can use something like this:

```
(SELECT id, created_by FROM content where created_by = 1 limit 5) 
union 
(SELECT id, created_by FROM content where created_by = 2 limit 5)
```

But I have about 20 users, so I do not think it is efficient.

Comment: I believe you can use this to get your required solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070927/mysql-many-to-many-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function, not available in MySQL:

```
SELECT ArticleId, UserId, UserName
FROM (
  SELECT a.id AS ArticleId, u.id AS UserId, u.name AS UserName,
         @row_number:= IF (@uid = u.id, 
                          IF (@uid:=u.id, @row_number+1, @row_number+1),
                          IF (@uid:=u.id, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM articles AS a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number:=0, @uid:=0) vars
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON a.created_by = u.id
  WHERE u.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  ORDER BY u.id, a.id ) t
WHERE t.rn <= 5
```

The above query will pick the top 5 articles per user (as per `articleId` ordering). If a user has less than 5 articles, then all articles of the user are selected.

Note the usage of *nested conditionals* in order to guarantee that `@uid` is *first* read and *subsequently* set.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cb38/3)

Comment: Thanks but I need solution for MySql.

Comment: @Israel That's exactly the point of my answer: it uses MySQL variables since `ROW_NUMBER` is not available in MySQL.

Comment: Giorgos thanks very much for your help! this is exactly what I wanted, you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: @Downvoter I would be grateful if you could explain the reason for your downvote, so that I can improve or even fix my answer, in case there is an error in it.

Comment: Your solution doesn't scale any better than his UNION for each user - you missed his '...' - implying he has a lot more than 6 users. OP, I'm guessing you don't want to hear the best way is to call MySQL from some language - e.g. PHP - and have an outer loop getting each user, then the inner loop getting his/her, up to 5, articles?

Comment: @user3741598 I doesn't scale? The `UNION` solution is performing *20 or more separate* queries in comparison to *just one* query my solution suggests. The OP can of course inform us about how my proposed solution compares to the `UNION` query he mentions in his post.

Comment: What I need to do is to get max 5 articles for each user (about 20 users), I can do it by one SQL that does not limit 5 articles per user, and then in PHP I can loop over the users and create the object I need. I thought running SQL that limit to 5 articles per user and then building the object is better?

Comment: @Israel IMHO it is better running a query like the one I propose, getting exactly the data you need and transfer exactly this data from DB to application Server. Otherwise you have to transfer the *whole* table from DB to the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work... (abstract implementation)

```
SELECT id_user FROM TABLE    
WHERE id_user IN 
 (SELECT id_user
  FROM TABLE 
  GROUP BY id_user 
  HAVING count(articles)<=5)
```

Comment: This will bring all users that have 5 or less articles, this is not what I want. I want to get max 5 articles of each user (if user has 10 articles, I want to get only 5 of them). the result should be articles and user_id where max articles per user is 5. Thanks

Comment: OK; show all users with >=5 articles and show maximum 5 articles per each user?